# Getting an extra blank item when splitting a string

Tags: c#

I'm splitting a string with "\0" separators and I'm getting an extra blank trailing item and I'm not sure why. There should be 5 parameters, each terminated by a "\0". Here is the string:

> Splash\0\0Message here.\01Back\0\0

here is my code:

```
var paramList = new List<string>(parameters.Split("\0".ToCharArray()));
```

here is why I'm getting:

```
[0] = "Splash"
[1] = ""
[2] = "Message here."
[3] = "1Back"
[4] = ""
[5] = ""
```

I can't remove the empty parameters when splitting since their position is important.

The string has 5 parameters/separators, but is returning 6 elements. Position is important because [0] is always the title, [1] the subtitle, [2] the message, [3] button 1, [4] button 2.

It's easy enough for me to just ignore the final item, but I'd like to know why it's there and what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: 5 separators means there will be 6 elements.  If you had a string with only one separator, you would get 2 elements.  If you only want 5 elements, then remove the last separator, it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong.  There is not an extra result.  It is working exactly as it should.

Split isn't for finding substrings that are terminated by the given separators, instead it splits substrings at the given separator.

Like cutting a loaf of bread, if you make 1 cut, you end up with 2 pieces.
If you make two cuts, you end up with 3 pieces.
If you make 3 cuts, you end up with 4 pieces.
and so on...

You have 5 cuts (5 "\0" separators), so you'll end up with 6 substrings.

If you don't want the last one, then just remove it.  There are plenty of ways to do that!  Search for "remove last element from List", "remove last element from array", or whichever your preferred container type is.

Answer (score 4):

Use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to remove empty entries

Replace

```
var paramList = new List<string>(parameters.Split("\0".ToCharArray()));
```

with

```
var paramList = new List<string>(parameters.Split("\0".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

To skip last empty item only, use

```
var parameters = "Splash\0\0Message here.\01Back\0\0";
var splitted = parameters.Split("\0".ToCharArray());
var paramList = new List<string>(splitted.Take(splitted.Length - 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Index 4 and 5 are "" because the string ends with two NULs.  To remove these you could do something like

```
const char NUL = '\0';
var paramList = new List<string>(parameters.TrimEnd(NUL).Split(NUL));
```

I'm not sure why you are making `paramList` a `List`.  `string.Split` returns an array of strings which should be fine for you.

```
var params = parameters.TrimEnd(NUL).Split(NUL);
```

Comment: You're right I don't need a list, but I can't remove the last two \0's, they're closing the 4th parameter 1Back and the 5th parameter which is an empty string

Comment: Split doesn't care if the string ends (closes) with the split character.  So you can still do `TrimEnd` and you will get an array of 5 items.

Answer (score 1):

> It's easy enough for me to just ignore the final item, but I'd like to know why it's there and what I'm doing wrong.

You're not doing anything wrong. `Split()` is doing exactly what it's supposed to do in this case.

```
"1,2".Split(',') -> ["1", "2"]
",".Split(',')   -> ["", ""]
"1,,".Split(',') -> ["1", "", ""]
```

If you had a CSV file that had 2 commas in the first line, you'd consider that file to have 3 headers, right? If the next line consisted only of two commas, you'd figure there were three values, and they'd all be empty strings. Likewise, a line with 4 separators is thought to have 5 values and (as in your example) one with 5 separators is thought to have 7 values..

In your case, the fact that the string ends with `'\0'` means that splitting that string will yield a final empty string at the end, which is exactly the behavior you're seeing.

If you're expecting your input to end with the same value that you're splitting the string on, that's fine: just ignore the final item, which should always be empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first five, use `Take(5)`?...

```
        string parameters = @"Splash\0\0Message here.\01Back\0\0";
        var paramList = new List<string>(parameters.Split(new string[] { @"\0" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Take(5));
        for(int i = 0; i < paramList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + ": " + paramList[i]);
        }
```