# Why there are empty string while trying to split a string in Java? And how to fix it?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, java-8

I am trying to split a string like this:

```
stringNumbers = "12.34+345.56+45-87.90*43.00";
String[] Operators = stringNumbers.split("[0-9.]");
```

in the console when I print operators I am getting this:

```
[, , , , , +, , , , , , +, , -, , , , , *]
```

The null characters are not my desired output. Why am I getting null charachters and how to solve the problem?

Comment: Please notice that: they are not null characters, but empty strings ("").

Comment: I think this website is not welcoming to the new comers. I do not understand why there are so many down-votes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're splitting by a single character, you would have to do this eagerly:

```
String[] Operators = stringNumbers.split("[0-9.]*");
```

Or you can filter the results:

```
String[] Operators = Arrays.stream(stringNumbers.split("[0-9.]"))
    .filter(str -> !str.equals(""))
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: stringNumbers.split("[0-9.]*"); prints few null characters too, filtering them fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @tanvirgeek no problem, consider marking as correct;>

Comment: use "[0-9.]+" will be better, however, the filter is still needed to remove the first empty string.

Comment: why it prints null characters? are there null characters between every char in a string?

Comment: First and last one come from regex beginning/ensing the string. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675757/getting-an-extra-blank-item-when-splitting-a-string

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to just collect those numbers, with a simple expression such as:

```
\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?
```

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?";
        final String string = "12.34+345.56+45-87.90*43.00\n"
             + "12+345+45.8-87*43";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: 12.34
Full match: 345.56
Full match: 45
Full match: 87.90
Full match: 43.00
Full match: 12
Full match: 345
Full match: 45.8
Full match: 87
Full match: 43
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vYdPLK/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/vYdPLK/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```java
String stringNumbers = "12.34+345.56+45-87.90*43.00";
String[] Operators = Arrays.stream(stringNumbers.split("[0-9.]+"))
                .filter(str -> !str.equals(""))
                .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Since you're filtering the same way I do, the change in result is none, so why bother?

Comment: dump the results of ```stringNumbers.split("[0-9]+")``` and ```stringNumbers.split("[0-9]")```, and you will why i got bothered.